# dynamically created object with ng-repeat - want to default that checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

so there are a ton of references in StackOverflow in relation to ng-repeat and checkboxes. However, I have tried them and still can't get this to work.

What I am trying to do is that on click of `{{address.bookName}}` all the contacts that are populated via ng-repeat are selected by default. I tried adding ng-checked = true and while it did superficially tick the checkboxes, it did not create the property of `receivers.selected[contact.firstName]` and it's corresponding value of `{{contact.contact}}`.

```
<ul data-ng-repeat='address in addressBook'>
    <li>
      <a data-ng-click='showContacts = !showContacts'>{{address.bookName}}</a>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-show='showContacts' data-ng-repeat='contact in address.addresses'>
          <label>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              ng-model='receivers.selected[contact.firstName]'
              name='selectedReceivers[]'
              ng-true-value = '{{contact.contact}}'
              ng-false-value='null'/>
            {{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}} - {{contact.contact}}
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

In my controller I have an object:

```
$scope.receivers = {
    selected: {}
};
```

In summary: on click of `{{address.bookName}}`, I would like all the contacts in address.addresses to be selected and therefore `$scope.receivers` to be populated with all the contacts' firstName and contact.

Comment: You can check my answer, that will give you idea to do it but if you still find any problem just let me know and provide me your jsfiddle to check your json object.

Answer (score 0):

`data-ng-show='showContacts == $parent.$index'`, This will show the particular address of clicked book-name.

You can make the check-boxes selected by `ng-checked= true`.

In your case, you can just apply the ng-model dynamically by using `$index (To get current / inner loop index)` and `$parent.$index (To get parent loop index)`.

```
<input type='checkbox' 
               ng-model="receivers.checked[$parent.$index][$index]"
               ng-checked="true"
               ng-true-value="{{contact}}"
               ng-false-value="null" />
```

Finally, copy of your scope variable using `angular.copy(element)`.

```
//Copy the scope variable
$scope.receivers.checked[index] = angular.copy($scope.addressBook[index].addresses);
```

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
  //Declare ng-model
  $scope.receivers = {
    selected: {},
    checked: {}
  };
  $scope.showSelected = function(parentIndex, index)
  {
    //Show hide particular contacts
    $scope.showContacts = index;
    //Copy the scope variable
    $scope.receivers.checked[index] = angular.copy($scope.addressBook[index].addresses);
  }
 $scope.addressBook = [{
    "_id": 1,
    'bookName': 'Family',
    'companyID': 1234,
    'creator': 1234,
    'addresses': [{
      'contact': '1234567890',
      'firstName': 'Bob',
      'lastName': 'Smith'
    }, {
      'contact': '1234567890',
      'firstName': 'Amy',
      'lastName': 'Smith'
    }, {
      'contact': '1234567890',
      'firstName': 'John',
      'lastName': 'Smith'
    }]
  }, {
    '_id': 2,
    'bookName': 'Friends',
    'companyID': 1234,
    'creator': 1234,
    'addresses': [{
      'contact': '1234567890',
      'firstName': 'Bruce',
      'lastName': 'Wayne'
    }, {
      'contact': '1234567890',
      'firstName': 'Clark',
      'lastName': 'Kent'
    }, {
      'contact': '1234567890',
      'firstName': 'Peter',
      'lastName': 'Parker'
    }]
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <h5 class="form-title">Select contacts:</h5>
  <ul data-ng-repeat='address in addressBook'>
    <li>
      <a data-ng-click='showSelected($parent.$index, $index)'>{{address.bookName}}</a>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-show='showContacts == $parent.$index' data-ng-repeat='contact in address.addresses'>
          <label>
            <input type='checkbox' 
                   ng-model="receivers.checked[$parent.$index][$index]"
                   ng-checked="true"
                   ng-true-value="{{contact}}"
                   ng-false-value="null" /> {{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}} - {{contact.contact}}
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h5 class="text-bold">Send to: {{receivers.checked}}</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - your method still doesn't select all the checkboxes on click of `<a data-ng-click='showContacts[$index] = true'>{{address.bookName}}</a>`

Comment: This will just show a particular contacts of a book, when you click on that bookname.. Regarding selection of checkbox I can show a way there. For more details you can create a jsfiddle, so I can check your problem and resolved it.

Comment: @Sabrina Understand that without seeing your json object / full code, we can just assumed your question and answer it as a idea only.

Comment: this is what i have right now - https://jsfiddle.net/75wzxLv3/. on click of each address book, when it populates, i am looking for it to be defaulted checked/selected and the ```$scope.receivers``` to be populated with the corresponding objects. Right now you have to manually select each checkbox to populate the ```$scope.receivers``` list

Comment: @Sabrina : I've created an example for your, please check now.

Comment: thanks for that - however, when i unselect - the object isn't removed from the `$scope.receivers.checked` array

Comment: Also I've read that ng-model and ng-checked shouldn't be used together.

Comment: @Sabrina Thanks for drawing my attention there, I've update my answer as per your need, now check the working example. And let me know if you still find any problem.